# How to get file/folder drag image overlay as in Windows Explorer for Vista/7?

Tags: image, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

I am C#, .NET WPF developer I'd like to have in my application drag and drop experience that looks like the one in Windows Explorer. In particular I'd like to have this nice looking image when dragging some file (I am creating file manager app).

[image]

I am not sure how to accomplish this, I guess there is some way to get from the shell this image so that I can include it in my dragging overlay but I am not sure how to do that. I notice that some software (eg. ImgBurn) does something like this but I am not sure how.

I am aware of this blog post with very useful info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adamroot/shell-style-drag-and-drop-in-net-part-3 
However I it doesn't provide example of how to get image overlay when dragging items in custom application.

Comment: You use the `IDragSourceHelper2::InitializeFromBitmap` method, passing a custom bitmap.

Comment: Ok but how do I get a bitmap from the shell that looks like the one from Windows Explorer? Note also that explorer handles separately dragging one item vs several items (files or folders) by providing appropriate overlay drag image.

Comment: SHGetFileInfo is one way. There are others. It wasn't clear to me whether the question was "How do I get this effect?" or "How do I get the bitmap so I can plug it into this effect that I know how to do?"

Comment: Question is basically about both, but more specifically about how to get that cool looking bitmap while dragging. I was hope there is some kind of method/component I can use and pass list of files/folder and get back a bitmap to represent those while dragging...

Comment: Worst case you can create an explorer browser, put your items in it, select the items, and then ask the explorer browser to generate a drag bitmap. But easier is probably just doing it yourself by combining the icons.